# Umbraco: can't find developer. Database connect to visual studio

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have a project all in local.
I connected the database with visual studio(SQL Server and Visual Studio 2013), I think I had all right, but I can't found the developer section in umbraco. 
in web.config

```
< add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=hotel;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|hotel.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In the section Users, I can't check developer because I can't see it.
I have no idea what I have to do, maybe is the db not connected? 
the user is the same that I use in other project and always worked.

And doesn't work either if I had #developer in the link of umbraco
Some idea for show the developer section? I searched in google and in umbraco.our, but I didn't find the correct answere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have not completed the setup.  Of if you have, the LocalDb is empty or corrupt.  Try to follow the setup as described in the [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/).

The first user you have created is automatically administrator, and will be able to access the settings and developer section.

If you are able to connect to the database (e.g. from Visual Studio), verify that you have correct data in your umbracoUser2app table.

You are using the DataDirectory in your connectionstring, also check that your .mdf file is not overwritten when launching your website from visual studio.

Comment: thank you :D I found that in umbracoUser2app there wasn't the correct data.